# Select numbers from a string

Tags: t-sql

I have this query i'm trying to get working that can extract decimal numbers from a string so they are their own columns. The goal is to then compare the values are order them, so they will also need to be converted to decimal ( Getting the numbers out of the string is main problem though)

The example i'm using is with the string "OrdRevenuePay 3200.00 -> 2836.07, OrdRate 3200.00 -> 2836.07"

I need to have each of the numbers in that string as their own column. What i have so far is able to select the first value, but the second value is returning other parts as well. This is the query i've been working with so far:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(128)
SET @str = 'OrdRevenuePay 3200.00 -> 2836.07, OrdRate 3200.00 -> 2836.07'
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX(' ',@str)+1,CHARINDEX('->',@str)-CHARINDEX(' ',@str)-1) as col1
,  SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('->',@str,1)+2,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(', OrdRate',@str,1)-1) as col2
```

Comment: please add sample output and input

Comment: Is there anything predictable about the input string, e.g. there are always four decimal values with some sort of punctuation between them, or could it be anything?

Comment: The values can range from 4 digits ( including the decimal) to 10 digits; The format of the string is always the same, I.E it will always start with "OrdRevenuePay [number1] -> [number2], OrdRate [Number3] -> [Number4]". I want each number in it's own column. End goal is have the query only return records where Number1 is greater than Number 2, and number 3 is greater than number4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(128)
SET @str = 'OrdRevenuePay 3200.00 -> 2836.07, OrdRate 3200.00 -> 2836.07'

; WITH ReplaceX
    AS (
        SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(@str,CHARINDEX(',',@str)-1),' -> ','`'),' ','~') + '|' +
        REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str) - CHARINDEX(',',@str) - 1),' -> ','}'),' ','{') + '^' AS NewString
        )

SELECT  SUBSTRING(NewString,CHARINDEX('~',NewString)+1,CHARINDEX('`',NewString)-CHARINDEX('~',NewString)-1),
        SUBSTRING(NewString,CHARINDEX('`',NewString)+1,CHARINDEX('|',NewString)-CHARINDEX('`',NewString)-1),
        SUBSTRING(NewString,CHARINDEX('{',NewString)+1,CHARINDEX('}',NewString)-CHARINDEX('{',NewString)-1),
        SUBSTRING(NewString,CHARINDEX('}',NewString)+1,CHARINDEX('^',NewString)-CHARINDEX('}',NewString)-1)
    FROM ReplaceX
```

Comment: This seems to work great! Can you confirm if i understood this correctly?In the CTE you're replacing the white spaces and other characters (' -> ' , ',' ) with those other characters so you can then define the position of the numbers better with charindex in the following substrings?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've simply taken what IS predictable and made it even easier to recognize. Note that because of multiple spaces and '-->' I essentially broke the string in half so I don't have to deal with the first vs. second appearance issue.